# Cannot get SQL script to run from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to get the following batch script to run a CSV writer SQL file

All the below script generates is the MySQL console imformation??

It works fine from the MySQL command line utlilty (from the mysql>), but I need this to be automatically scheduled and ran from WINDOWS as a .bat file.

I ran it just fine as `mysql> \. path\csvwriter.sql`,  but not per the script below?  Am I missing something?

```
SET OutputDir=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads
SET mysqldir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
SET selectScript=C:\SQLScripts\csvwriter.sql

DEL %OutputDir%\drillsawdata.csv /F

CD %mysqldir%

mysql -h %host% -u %username% -p %password% arp < %selectScript%
```

Comment: @JohnWyss  I quoted the paths per your suggestion.  No console now, but I get the following error:  The filename, directory name, or volume lable syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your paths with quotes.  The spaces in the path name are the issue.